# Where to put 'use strict' in Browserify bundle

Tags: javascript, browserify

In a Browsersify bundle (containing many modules from many files), where should `use strict` appear to ensure the entire bundle is run in strict mode?

Comment: Doing this would be likely to break any NPM modules you're using which aren't built for strict mode. Why do you want to do this? You should add 'use strict'; onto your own code only.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you need to alter browserify output in a uniform way, the answer is usually to use a transform.

[strictify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/strictify) appears to do what you need.